# How start Mongo Instance in sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I want to deploy a sharded cluster for this i using MongoDB manual.
first i created 3 config servers.
mongod --configsvr --dbpath /data/configdb1 --port 27019 ,
mongod --configsvr --dbpath /data/configdb2 --port 27019  ,
mongod --configsvr --dbpath /data/configdb3 --port 27019

But in second step to Start the mongos Instances   i find a command like
mongos --configdb cfg0.example.net:27019,cfg1.example.net:27019,cfg2.example.net:27019

but i can't understand the meaning of

```
cfg0.example.net
cfg1.example.net
cfg2.example.net
```

So Please explain meaning of above command and how can i use this according my hostname?

Answer (score 1):

Please check ["Deploy a Sharded Cluster"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/), cfg[0-3].example.net means hostnames of 3 config servers, each of mongos server should be started with all config servers configured.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your issue

```
[ne@server1~]$mongos configdb"repl/localhost:57040,localhost:57041,localhost:57042" --fork --logpath log.mongos0 --port 27200
    about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
    forked process: 2467
```

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

These are are the config servers connected to the the mongos server

Comment: you could also check the mongodb documnetation